# Model folds in on itself when i try and rotate it in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode

Im trying to rotate my model 90 degrees to that the symmetrize function works correctly, but it ends up with bizzare results when i try and do so?

The same thing appears to be happenning with other objects like clothing as well, not just the body.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Give us more info, show modifiers tab, it looks like maybe mirror problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the *Symmetry* option on the top right:

[image]